# Short phrase for providing and taking care of technical aspects of an event

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, technical

I'm translating a local company site into English and I'm struggling to find a nice and compact way to describe one of the company's services.

Basically, if you are an organizer of an event of some sort (e.g., a conference), you can hire the company to provide all the technical equipment you need (microphones, interpreter consoles, projectors and similar), take care of the sound of the event (e.g. speakers), and provide staff who install the equipment and operate it during the course of the event. In a nutshell, the company takes care of everything related to technical issues.

I'm looking for a short phrase that could serve as a headline under which a list of references could be displayed. I've come up with some suggestions, but none sounds right to me:

- technical assistance with events
- technical coverage of events

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "a headline under which a list of references could be displayed"? Are the references testimonials from satisfied customers who've used your services?

Comment: @rhetorician It's a list of important large-scale conferences and events the company has covered.

Comment: Sounds like playing "roadie" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those services are referred to as ***"audio visual services"*** and can be found on the internet as "audio visual solutions", "event audio visual solutions" or "conference audio visual solutions".

Comment: Sorry, but sounds like servicios audio visuales sounds in Spanish or like French from 20 years ago. And none of these imply simultaneous or conference interpretation equipment and services,.It sounds like you do not know the industry in English. Sorry, just saying the truth.

Comment: Events with simultaneous or conference interpreting require specific audio equipment. That is not the same at all as regular audio visual equipment. In fact, there is no visual in it at all. The OP was mixing two separate domains. In any case, I'd say: audio visual equipment and services for conferences and events (if there is no interpreting). Personally, I  would not adjectivize event or conference.

Comment: Simultaneous or conference interpreting does not require projectors. I guess you didn't understand my comment. I never implied that audio visual equipment does not imply projectors. Yes, there is something to quibble about: the OP has confused domains and you have written your answer for types of events that do not include **conference interpreting**.

Comment: @Lambie, not my downvotes.  You may know interpreting but 1) that wasn't the OP's primary question and 2) you implied I'm not a native speaker, which was untrue and offensive.  Naughty! :-)

Comment: No, not not a native speaker.  It just sounded translated to me. Not the same thing. The OP's question was mixed up. That's all. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

The companies that do what you describe do: conference interpretation equipment rentals and services

I would not use the word technical. Sounds like translationese. My reference is myself: I know the industry.
That said, here is a company that does just that: http://www.lexiconusa.com/pages/SImultaneous-Interpretation.html